# How would I paginate this data?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

How would you paginate this?
The data is called by the "getInstance" queries below which then display a number of records called "pages" whis are listed in the dynamic table.

I would like to be able to display only 10 "pages" per query and paginate them onward

```
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="std">

        <?php   


        $counter = 1;
        $userID = PageDB::getInstance()->get_user_id_by_name($_SESSION['user']);
        $result = PageDB::getInstance()->get_pages_by_campaign_id($campaignID);
        $i=0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
             $style = "";
                if($i%2==0)
{
    $style = ' style="background-color: #EFEFEF"';
}
echo "<tr".$style.">";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";


            //The loop is left open
            ?>
            <td>
            <form style="display:none;"></form>
            <div id="Pagination" class="pagination"> </div>
    <div id="Searchresult"> </div>
                <form name="editPage" action="editPage.php" method="GET">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="<?php echo $pageID = $row['pid']; ?>" />
                    <input type="submit" name="editPage"  value="<?php echo "Page "  . $counter; ?>" style="background:none;border:none; cursor:pointer"/>
                </form>

            </td>
            <td>
                <form name="deletePage" action="deletePage.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="<?php echo $pageID = $row['pid']?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="deletePage" value="Delete" onclick = "javascript: return confirm('Delete Page <?php echo $counter ?> ?');"/>
                </form>
            </td>              
            <?php
            $pageID = $row['pid'];  
            $counter++;
            $i++;

            echo "</tr>\n";
        endwhile;
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        ?>
    </table>
```

The queries refference these 2 public functions which call the users id in order to call the corellating pages from the DB:

```
 public function get_user_id_by_name($name) {
    $name = $this->real_escape_string($name);
    $user = $this->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = '" . $name . "'");

    if ($user->num_rows > 0){
        $row = $user->fetch_row();
        return $row[0];
    } else
        return null;
}

public function get_pages_by_campaign_id($campaignID) {
    $campaignID = $this->real_escape_string($campaignID);
    return $this->query("SELECT pid , campaignid FROM pages , campaigns WHERE campaignid = campaigns.id");
}
```

Can anyone see a solution? Thank you!

Comment: the keyword here is `LIMIT` in your query which you need to add. There are too many tutorials on google. Try one. If you get stuck, then tell us where you got stuck. what's not working. etc....

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT queries in MySQL.

```
SELECT pid , campaignid 
FROM pages , campaigns 
WHERE campaignid = campaigns.id
LIMIT first_record_number, how_many_records
```

[PEAR Pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager) can help you get current page number etc.

```
 $pager_options = array(
    'mode'       => 'Sliding',
    'perPage'    => 10,
    'delta'      => 2,
    'totalItems' => $total_count,
 );

 $pager = Pager::factory($pager_options);

 list($from, $to) = $pager->getOffsetByPageId();
 //TODO: get and display data from database
 //first_record_number = $from-1
 //how_many_records = 10

 //show the links
 echo $pager->links;
```

My advice is to use virualization library to communicate with database eg. [AdoDB](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/). There is method:

```
$rs = $conn->SelectLimit("SELECT pid , campaignid 
FROM pages , campaigns 
WHERE campaignid = campaigns.id", how_many_records,first_record_number);
$arr1 = $rs->GetArray();
```

It can also do filtering of input data, geting all results as array and many other useful things.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot load Pear or extensions thereof onto the server in question :-S

Comment: This extension doesn't use any other PEAR classes so you can download it manualy and extract to sources of your app. Change paths in `require` if necesary, and replace/remove `PEAR::raiseError` in `Common.php`